# Gradient Descent for Multi-Level / Mixed / Hierarchical Regression Model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, gradient-descent, hierarchical-bayesian

How would gradient descent work in a multilevel regression setting? This is fairly clear to me in a standard linear regression formulation, but haven't been able to wrap my head around parameter updates in hierarchical models.

In short, I'd like to be able to make sequential updates to an existing model in a online-ish format (we'll see new data every *t* timesteps, and would actually like to bias the updates towards newer observations but that's potentially another conversation), where the idea would be to have better informed parameter estimates over time. My thought was that hand-coding a gradient descent update step would be a potential solution, but need to figure out how this would work given the hierarchical structure of the data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.